# How to upload/download files from firebase using matlab?

Tags: matlab, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need to upload and download files using matlab.I tried "https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/webwrite.html" but it didn't work.
Tried a code in matlabtools:

```
clear all; close all; clc;
thingSpeakURL = 'https://deneme-b25e4.firebaseio.com/';
thingSpeakWriteURL = [thingSpeakURL 'update'];
writeApiKey = '****************************************';
fieldName = 'field1';
fieldValue = 42;
response = webwrite(thingSpeakWriteURL,'api_key',writeApiKey,fieldName,fieldValue)
```

Error using readContentFromWebService (line 46)
The server returned the status 405 with message "Method Not Allowed" in response to the request to URL
https://deneme-b25e4.firebaseio.com/update.

Comment: You should read the [firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database/) REST API documentation. There is no such thing as `...firebaseio.com/update`.

Comment: And also you should avoid to share your api key and your user_id !